# How does classList work?

Tags: javascript, dom

I've been trying to use classList as described in the documentation here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

However, I keep getting errors in the browser saying 'contains' or 'add' is undefined.  I don't understand why.

I've used:

```
for (i = 0; i < card.length; i++) {
        card[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
            this.classList.toggle('open');
            this.classList.toggle('show');
        });
```

And classList works great!!. However, when I write:

```
 let flipped = document.classList.contains('open');
```

I get the error "contains" is undefined.

If anybody can explain to me how these uses of classList are different I would be incredibly thankful!!

Side Note: I'm using pure javascript and troubleshooting in chrome

Comment: The title of the linked MDN article is "_Element.classList_". The said object is a property of elements only, `document` doesn't have it. Notice, that the error message is "_Cannot read property 'contains' of undefined_", that means `document.classList` being `undefined`. In FireFox the error messge is more clear: "_document.classList is undefined_".

Comment: `document.body.classList` is work.

Comment: @flowerszhong, because **[`body`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/body)** is an element. See my answer.

Comment: A `document` has no attributes, and no `class` either. Did you mean `document.documentElement` maybe`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this error because **[`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)** is the object in **[`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element)** and not in **[`document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document)**.

**Fox example:**

```js
var flipped = document.classList; //undefined
console.log(flipped); //undefined
```

And then if you try to use `flipped.contains` you get an error because `flipped` is `undefined`.